# Whats wrong with my ( Password ) function?

Tags: c, char

I have copied this function from the web. I don't understand what does `c == 8 && pos` means in this function and `ch` is a char how can be it equal to `8`. I want to change the length of password to 4 which is now 13. When I tried to change and compile it. The program ran successfully but it does not stop taking password and even upon pressing enter it didn't stop taking input password.

I think it has to do something with `c == 8 && pos` in the following function.

```
void password(char buffer[])
{
        char c;
        int pos = 0;
            printf("Enter Password : ");
        do
            {
             c = getch();
                if( isprint(c) )
                {
                    buffer[ pos++ ] = c;
                    printf("%c", '*');
                }
                else if( c == 8 && pos )
                {
                    buffer[ pos-- ] = '\0';
                    printf("%s", "\b \b");
                }
            }while( c != 8 );
}
```

Comment: The 8 is an ASCII backspace character, that part is handling removing a character when you press the backspace key.

Comment: `13` is the ASCII code for `Enter` key. `while (c != 13);` would stop getting input after hitting `Enter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c==8 is checking if the [ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com/) value is equal to the backspace character.  && pos is also checking if the position is not zero.  it is equivalent to "pos != 0". The code is removing backspace characters from the buffer.  Also, this function can be prone to a buffer overflow.  Since you are passing in the address of buffer, but no maximum size, what happens when the user enters a string longer than the allocated memory.  You should pass in the buffer length also as a parameter, and validate that pos < buffer length.